# Augmented Reality Browser for windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am using augmented reality in my application in windows phone 7.
I want to know that is there any library available which can be used in my application for augmented reality. There is a wikitude browser available in android or iphone for AR implementation. so is there any browser or library available for windows phone 7 application development with augmented reality

Answer (score 3):

http://slartoolkit.codeplex.com/

Is one